# Laravel Schema not returning true on column that exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am running larval right now and have a controller with a method that will determine if a column exists in a table for a given table name.

```
public function checkColumnExists($name){
    return Schema::hasColumn($this->table_name,$name);
}
```

I also have schema imported at the top of the controller. When I have a table with a. completed_at column for example and I pass that name into the function it will always return false. The table name is passed in with a parameter in the url its the name of the Model and is converted to snake case with the helper function laravel has

Comment: For me, this works as expected with plaintext variables; likely an issue with the variables being used. Try some logging/debugging; add a `\Log::info($this->table_name."|".$name);` (or something similar) and examine what's being logged in `storage/logs`; compare it manually and see if everything is behaving as expected.

Comment: Can yo try with passing real table name and column name and try and out put those two before it if it is successful?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I tried the same and still got false with every table and column